# Registering accounts on new sites through android app

Tags: feature-request, accounts, android-app, registration, draft

I have a few feature requests for the app.

I tried to "favorite" a post on a site I'm not a user of and I got this error message:

> The account associated with the access_token does not have a user on the site

(1) I think it would be extremely useful if you can register for sites through the app after getting this error message.

As far as I can tell you can only pin sites through the app menu, which isn't the same thing as joining.

Also I tried to post this feature request earlier through the app. But because I wasn't a member of Meta I lost my post.

The app just gave me a bad error message saying it lost my post and that it may have been deleted. It was quite a bad user experience but luckily my first message was short.

(2) If the post fails to submit, it should save it in your drafts. Or have a better explanation other than my post doesn't exist.

(3) Additionally, when you press the ask question button, it should check that I'm not a member on a site when I try to post and then prompt me to register.

Thanks! 
Miguel